# How to apply condition to checkbox in Angular-12 FormArray

Tags: angular

I have FormArray in Angular-12 as shown below:. I am working on employee work experience, and this will be in form of a FormArray that will be dynamically generated at the click of add button.

```js
This is the component as shown below:

export class ExperienceFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() experienceDetailsForm: FormGroup;
  data: Candidate;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private candidateService: CandidateService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.experienceDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
      experiences: this.fb.array([this.createExperienceFormGroup()]),
    });
  }

  public addExperienceFormGroup() {
    const experiences = this.experienceDetailsForm.get('experiences') as FormArray;
    experiences.push(this.createExperienceFormGroup());
  }

  public removeOrClearExperience(i: number) {
    const experiences = this.experienceDetailsForm.get('experiences') as FormArray;
    if (experiences.length > 1) {
      experiences.removeAt(i);
    } else {
      experiences.reset();
    }
  }

  private createExperienceFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      designation: new FormControl(''),
      type: new FormControl(''),
      location: new FormControl(''),
      organization: new FormControl(''),
      startDate: new FormControl(''),
      endDate: new FormControl(''),
      current: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  addExperienceDetails() {
    if (this.experienceDetailsForm.dirty) {
      this.data = this.candidateService.getCandidateDetails();
      this.data.experience = this.experienceDetailsForm.value.experiences;
      this.candidateService.setCandidateDetails(this.data);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Also I have the HTML form for the form array:

<div class="card-body">

  <div formArrayName="experiences">
    <div *ngFor="let experience of experienceDetailsForm.get('experiences')['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="designation" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Position
                                        {{i+1}}:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" id='designation' maxlength="20" onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your designation"
            formControlName="designation" required>
        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="type" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Employment
                                        type:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <select id="type" name="type" class="form-control" formControlName="type">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Your employment type</option>
            <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
            <option value="fulltime">Full-time</option>
            <option value="internship">Internship</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="float-left" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Add" (click)="addExperienceFormGroup()" matTooltip="Add">
                                            <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
          <button class="float-left" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Remove/clear" (click)="removeOrClearExperience(i)" matTooltip="Remove">
                                            <mat-icon>highlight_off</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="organization" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Company:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="text" id='organization' maxlength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" formControlName="organization" required>
        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Starting
                                        date:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="date" id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value="" formControlName="startDate" required>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Location:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Company location" type="text" maxlength="15" formControlName="location" required>
        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="endDate" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-nowrap">Ending
                                        date:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value="" formControlName="endDate" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <mat-checkbox class="col-12" formControlName="current" color="primary">Currently working here</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want:

```
<mat-checkbox class="col-12" formControlName="current" color="primary">Currently working here</mat-checkbox>
```

because employee cannot be working in more than a place at a time.
How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: @Prakash - Sorry can you format it. It's not clear.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable called HasCheckedCurrentlyWorking

You can trigger a function on your checkbox  onchange

```
<mat-checkbox [disabled]="HasCheckedCurrentlyWorking  && !experience.CurrentlyWorking " (change)="SetCurrentlyWOrking(i)" class="col-12" formControlName="current" color="primary">Currently working here</mat-checkbox>
```

Create a function in your ts file and set it as CurrentlyWorking to true.

In-case you have selected a checkbox as currently working, your other checkboxes will be marked as disabled except the selected ones

**In Your TS**

```
HasCheckedCurrentlyWorking: boolean = false;
SetCurrentlyWOrking(i): void {

var experiences = this.experienceDetailsForm.get('experiences') as FormArray;
if (experiences[i].current == false) {
  experiences[i].current = true;
  this.HasCheckedCurrentlyWorking = true;
}
else {
  experiences[i].current = false;
  this.HasCheckedCurrentlyWorking = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the example of the function in the component

Comment: Have updated. Check it should give an idea of how to do it.